# Recovering the index from the maximum value

Tags: r

Simple reproducible example:

```
a=c(1,3,2,7,4,2,5,6,7)
```

max(a) gives me the maximum value

a==max(a) gives me the elements which have maximum value

Now I need to recover the index(es) from the elements which have maximum value, so in this example elements number 4 and 9. Do I need to use a while/for cycle or there's a less memory consuming solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the first `min` or `max`, you can use `which.min` and `which.max`.  Otherwise, you can subset:

```
a[a==max(a)]
```

You can also use `match` and `which` for variations on this theme:

```
which(a==max(a))
```

To return the indicies...

Comment: I understand how the which.max functions works, but my question is if this is less memory consuming than using a cycle. When I see the function syntax R gives me: which.min
function (x) 
.Internal(which.min(x))
<bytecode: 0x000000001a569938>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: On an unsorted vector, you cannot find the indexes of the max values in a single pass.  I think it is a fairly safe assumption that the internal R functions (especially ones written in fortran or C) are about as optimized as they can be for speed and memory.